# How to define default values or accept empty html input controls in ASP.NET Core method

Tags: html, forms, asp.net-core

I have a form with a bunch of controls, but not everyone is required to fill in, so I get an error when I receive the form because some values are not present. I've tried to define default values on the function, but I think it's the `[FromForm]` that is causing the error.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="AddressLine1" name="AddressLine1" class="txt-antan address-line" onkeyup="verifyInput()" onchange="verifyInput()" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="AddressLine2" name="AddressLine2" class="txt-antan address-line" onkeyup="verifyInput()" onchange="verifyInput()" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="AddressLine3" name="AddressLine3" class="txt-antan address-line" onkeyup="verifyInput()" onchange="verifyInput()" value="-" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="AddressLine4" name="AddressLine4" class="txt-antan address-line" onkeyup="verifyInput()" onchange="verifyInput()" value="-" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="AddressLine5" name="AddressLine5" class="txt-antan address-line" onkeyup="verifyInput()" onchange="verifyInput()" placeholder="@_local["WordAddresss"]" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

AddressLine 3 to 5 are not required and may be empty.

```
[HttpPost("API/SetCartIdentity")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SetCartIdentityAsync([FromForm(Name = "AddressLine1")] string addressLine1, [FromForm(Name = "AddressLine2")] string addressLine2, [FromForm(Name = "AddressLine3")] string addressLine3, [FromForm(Name = "AddressLine4")] string addressLine4, [FromForm(Name = "AddressLine5")] string addressLine5 = "default value")
{
    return RedirectToActionPermanent("Checkout", "Cart");
}
```

It will cause an error if any of the input's are empty.

Comment: You could add `?` after the datatype in your model. Something like `public string? Genre { get; set; }`. The question mark after the string indicates that the property is nullable. [See Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-a-data-model-class).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a class for your input model similar to this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    namespace MySample
    {
        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
            public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
            public string AddressLine4 { get; set; }
            public string AddressLine5 { get; set; } = "default value";
        }
    }
```

Then, your method signature would look like this:

```
[HttpPost("API/SetCartIdentity")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SetCartIdentityAsync(InputModel model)
{
    return RedirectToActionPermanent("Checkout", "Cart");
}
```

You could then also review the form tag helpers available: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0#the-input-tag-helper

And the validation components here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: thank you for answering. I tried it out but I get "Unsupported Media Type". I tried to use GET form method with the same result. If I added [FromForm] it started bitching about the address lines, just as before.

Comment: If you are posting to an API directly from a Form, take a look at this for Form-urlencoded Data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-1